# How do I access my jail by hostname on a home network?

Tags: freebsd, jails, freenas

I'm using FreeNAS (FreeBSD), and I've created a jail, and I've given the jail a hostname, and I can access the jail via IP address, but I can't access the jail by it's hostname. (within my home network)

I think I somehow need to get local DNS working? But on a home network, I don't have a proper DNS? I am not sure how name resolution works on home networks.

i.e. I can make http://192.168.1.42:8000 and the jail responds to those requests.

on the jail:

```
root@jailname:/ # hostname
jailname
```

but on other computers on the network:

```
mckay@mckays-macbook ~ % ping jailname
ping: cannot resolve jailname: Unknown host
```

```
C:/> ping jailname
Ping request could not find host jailname. Please check the name and try again
```

FWIW, I can resolve my NAS and my mac by hostname on a windows machine, but a mac can't get the hostname of the NAS or the windows machine. (but it can ping them by IP).

Android devices can get name resolution on the NAS.

Comment: You add an entry for your jail host in the name lookup system. This might be the /etc/hosts file or you might need to setup DNS. Can you ping "mckays-macbook" from your windows machine?

Comment: Yes. I can ping my mac and the NAS from my windows machine.
Perhaps interestingly, the mac can't ping the windows machine or the NAS

Comment: @icarus What did you mean by "add an entry for your jail host in the name lookup system? i.e. in my hosts file? I don't want to do that for all the computers on the network, and I haven't had to do that for my NAS. My gut says it's a configuration issue on the jail or the NAS's jail system, for the above reasons.

Comment: Networking works on the basis of IP addresses. There are services which translates names to IP addresses. When you say "ping name" the ping program uses those services to translate the name to an address, and then sends packets to that address.

Comment: The main translation service is the DNS. This is how you find google.com, facebook.com, cnn.com, mit.edu, whitehouse.gov and so on. There are other services that only work for the LAN. The fact that you have 3 devices, NAS, Mac and windows, and the Mac can't talk to the NAS or the windows shows that you don't have a good setup currently. It is unlikely that altering the configuration on the NAS will allow the Mac to ping the windows machine. You almost certainly have a router. Can you ping that by name from your 3 devices? The standards based solution you want is to set up a local DNS service

Comment: @icarus Yeah, I'm familiar with DNS from a TLD perspective, but I'm not sure how it works for machines on a home network. I have a router, but I'm not sure what the hostname would be for the router.

Answer (score 0):

Your home network has a router and a modem (or terminal adapter) that connects it to the internet. You might also have an access point (AP), or more likely, your router has an integrated AP that lets you connect to the router via WiFi. Two of the services your router provides your LAN are DHCP and DNS resolution. DNS resolution is provided during DHCP when the router tells IP clients where to find the DNS resolver.

By default, most routers gives out their own local IP address for DNS resolution. When DNS requests arrive, they proxy the DNS requests from the LAN to upstream DNS resolvers. Those upstream DNS resolvers might belong to your ISP or if you're a bit more clever, you go into your router settings and choose a better (faster, more privacy respecting, more reliable, etc.) set of public DNS resolvers.

The DNS resolvers your router depends on are outside your home LAN and have no knowledge of the hosts on your LAN that are typically hidden behind your routers NAT and/or firewall.

There are some self configuring protocols that let IPv4 hosts talk to each other on the LAN using hostnames (NETBIOS, AppleTalk, zeroconf/multicast DNS), but each has limited support. Your router might even have support for one or more of those protocols, letting you access hostnames on your LAN via their name. In order for that to work, your router must support it and you must install a client for that protocol that publishes the name(s) of your local hosts.

On FreeBSD, have a look at the ports mDNSResponder and avahi for configuring Multicast DNS, netatalk for AppleTalk over IP, and samba for NETBIOS. I have used all of the above for many years and each works to varying degree.

If you want a bulletproof "always works" solution for hostname resolution via both IPv4 and IPv6, then run [unbound](https://nlnetlabs.nl/projects/unbound/about/) on your FreeBSD host and bind it to a static IP address on your LAN. By convention, I run a DNS server at the next highest IP address on the LAN above the router. So if the router is 192.168.1.1, then DNS is published at 192.168.1.2. Then configure your router to use the static IP address of your local DNS server for DHCP assignment.

Now that you have a local DNS server, you can configure it with the local A, AAAA, and PTR records needed for dependable DNS resolution within your LAN. When configured thusly, every host on your LAN can access your static hosts via their DNS name.